# Proving number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing, combinations

Given a binary number of length n there are $2^n$ representations of this number. So 101 has 8 representations. The 2 in $2^n$ can be generalized p where p is number of states within a number. So for binary numbers p is 2 , for decimal numbers p is 10. Is there a proof that exists which shows for a digit p the number of representations of that number is $p^n$ were n is the length of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the $n$-digit number as an $n$-dimensional vector:
$$
101=(1,0,1)
$$
Then the question becomes: How many $n$-dimensional vectors with coordinates in $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ are there?

Now we can show inductively that there must be $p^n$ such up till some value of $n$ and prove from there that it works for $n+1$ by taking all $n$-dimensional vectors and add another coordinate to form an $(n+1)$-dimensional vector. Thus the choice of the $(n+1)$-th coordinate among $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ leads to $p$ new vectors formed from each old vector:
$$
p\cdot p^n=p^{n+1}
$$
and there you have it.

Comment: why ask the question "How many n-dimensional vectors with coordinates in {0,1,2,...,p−1} are there " ? Does your solution also work for " How many n-dimensional vectors with coordinates in {0,1,2,...,p} are there" ? Why use p-1 instead of just p ?

Comment: @blue-sky: In the base $10$ system, the decimal system, we use digits $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$. In base $2$ we use $\{0,1\}$. In base $p$ ...?

Comment: subtracting 1 in order to provide a valid possible value, value 10 does not exist in base 10 , value 2 does not exist in base 2 ->  so subtract 1.

Comment: @blue-sky: Yes. Note that this still means that there are $p$ values in the set of digits, since we are counting from $0$.